# In Elm, how do I fire a Cmd once a page has been routed to?

Tags: elm

I have an Elm SPA that has a page that includes a chart. I'm using a JS port to activate a chart.js chart. When the page is loaded, I'd like to send the chart data via the port. I'm able to wire the commands up fine on events (like a select change, for example), but am at a loss for how to get the command to fire when the page is loaded.

I tried wiring up the command in my app's init, but of course this fires before I've retrieved my app data.

Thanks much!

Some sample code:
(I'm creating the Cmd with "chart", with is the name of my port, which takes along with it chart data based on my model.)

Main.elm

```
init : Result String Route -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init result =
    let
        currentRoute =
            Routing.routeFromResult result
    in
        ( initialModel currentRoute, Cmd.map VendorsMsg fetchAll )


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.none


urlUpdate : Result String Route -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
urlUpdate result model =
    let
        currentRoute =
            Routing.routeFromResult result
    in
        ( { model | route = currentRoute }, chart (computeChartData model) )


main : Program Never
main =
    Navigation.program Routing.parser
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , urlUpdate = urlUpdate
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }
```

Routing.elm

```
type Route
    = HomeRoute
    | AdminRoute
    | EditVendorRoute VendorId
    | NotFoundRoute


matchers : Parser (Route -> a) a
matchers =
    oneOf
        [ format HomeRoute (s "")
        , format EditVendorRoute (s "admin" </> int)
        , format AdminRoute (s "admin")
        ]


hashParser : Navigation.Location -> Result String Route
hashParser location =
    location.hash
        |> String.dropLeft 1
        |> parse identity matchers


parser : Navigation.Parser (Result String Route)
parser =
    Navigation.makeParser hashParser


routeFromResult : Result String Route -> Route
routeFromResult result =
    case result of
        Ok route ->
            route

        Err string ->
            NotFoundRoute
```

Comment: Are you using [`elm-lang/navigation`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/navigation/latest)? If so, couldn't you return a `Cmd` which notifies your port in `urlUpdate`?

Comment: I am using elm-lang/navigation. Let me see if I can figure that out!

Comment: Brilliant - that now works when I navigate to the page from another page in my app. Still doesn't load when I type the URL into my location bar (say myapp.com/#chart). Any ideas how to get that to work? Thank you!

Comment: Can you add some more example code to your question? The [Counter example for the `elm-lang/navigation`](https://github.com/elm-lang/navigation/blob/1.0.0/examples/Counter.elm) package fires correctly (via Debug.log verification) when hitting a url from the browser, so it may be something more subtle in your implementation.

Comment: Code added. Let me know if it helps at all. Thanks again!

Comment: Is it firing in the counter example just because urlUpdate is being called from init?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, and that's an alternative solution to my answer. If you forced it through urlUpdate, you'd get the result you desire.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to fire your `chart` port during the `init` function, given your initial model:

```elm
init : Result String Route -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init result =
    let
        currentRoute =
            Routing.routeFromResult result
        model =
            initialModel currentRoute
    in
        ( model, Cmd.batch [ Cmd.map VendorsMsg fetchAll, chart (computeChartData model) ] )
```

This should ensure that the port is fired even if you type the URL into the browser manually.

Answer (score -1):

You can use flags to pass initial data to your program on page load. So if you are worried that you need initial data when the page loads just pass it into the elm code.